# how to get monthly date in teradata

Tags: teradata

I have a table called oth_mbr. I need to get 3 years of data month wise. current date minus 36 months and each month data betwwe from_dt and thru_dt needs to be fetched.

data shoulbe be in below formate

```
DATE , COLUMN A, COLUMN B
2017-08-01,FEP000,FPr
2017-09-01,FEP000,FPr
2017-10-01,FEP000,FPr
.
.
.
2020-08-01,FEP000,FPr
```

tried below query but this gives only one data

```
SEL distinct ADD_MONTHS(DATE - DATE MOD 100 + 1,- 36)  AS   DATE ,
COLUMN 1,COLUMN 2
OTH_MBR 
WHERE 
ADDD_MONTHS(DATE - DATE MOD 100 + 1,- 36)  BETWEEN FROM_DT AND THRU_DT

Result for above query is 
2017-08-01,FEP000,FPr
```

Comment: Are `from_dt` abd `thru_dt` columns in your table? And you want one row per month for the last tree years when they match from/thru

Comment: yes, from_dt and thru_dt columns are there in my table and get all data when that month data is between from_dt and thru_dt

example : check 2017-08-01 is inbetween from_dt and thru_dt and fetch that records and finally count them

Answer (score 0):

Teradata supports proprietary syntax for time series expansion:

```
select begin(pd), column1, column2
from OTH_MBR 
expand on period (from_dt, thru_dt) as pd
by anchor period month_begin
-- if you want to restrict the range of months
for period(ADD_MONTHS(current_date,- 36), current_date )
```

You can wrap it in a Derived Table/CTE for further processing:

```
with cte as 
 (
   select begin(pd) as mon, column1, column2
   from OTH_MBR 
   expand on period (from_dt, thru_dt) as pd
   by anchor period month_begin
   for period(ADD_MONTHS(current_date,- 36), current_date )
 )
select mon, count(*)
from cte
group by 1;
```